# How can i check pathname is exist in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a pathname like this:

```
'/student/projects/41XrUP7E2-fHhOfzIK'

"/student/projects/41XrUP7E2-fHhOfzIK/edit"
```

and array of router path:

```
['/student/project/:contactid/school', "/student/projects/:projectId/edit", "/orderers/projects/:projectId"]
```

How can i check pathname is exist in app?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by doing that check?

Comment: Are you using react-router and trying to setup a 404 page for non existing routes ?

Comment: Fetch it and have your api respond with a 404 if it doesn't exist